# Best Practice query count value in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have some tables
table Analytic :

```
room_id | diag_in | indicator_in | etc..

22      | 0       |    1
23      | 1       |    0
23      | 1       |    1
22      | 0       |    1
```

**And I want to Output :**

```
room_id | total  

22      | 2       
23      | 3
```

```sql
SELECT room_id,SUM(total) AS total FROM(

SELECT room_id, COUNT(indicator_in) total
FROM Analytic 
WHERE indicator_in='1'
GROUP BY room_id
UNION
SELECT room_id, COUNT(`diag_in`) total
FROM Analytic 
WHERE diag_in='1'
GROUP BY room_id
) abc
GROUP BY room_id
```

Its Working... but how to simple code if i have 23 column in my Table and I will Implement in Laravel, it's so long code.... ,How to simple code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a group by and sum to count both columns together.

In SQL:

```
SELECT room_id, (SUM(indicator_in) + SUM(diag_in)) as total
FROM Analytic
GROUP BY room_id
```

Using Laravel query builder:

```
DB::table('Analytic')
    ->groupBy('room_id')
    ->select(
        'room_id',
        DB::raw('(SUM(indicator_in) + SUM(diag_in)) as total')
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Damn, you've been faster than me. :/ You can use that [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vTcR6qqLtPdJhnaFLrNpbN/0)

Comment: hahaha what I was thinking was to make such a complicated query...so thank you